# Inserting a new record to PostgreSQL with default values from PetaPoco (and Npgsql)

Tags: database, postgresql, petapoco

In PostgreSQL (9.5), I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE icd9
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  code text,
  cdesc text NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT pk_icd9_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid)
)
```

Using PetaPoco, I have the following statement:

```
 icd9 newicd9 = db.SingleOrDefault<icd9>("select * from icd9 where lower(cdesc) = lower(@0)", newdx.cdesc);

 if (newicd9 == null)
 {       
       newicd9 = new icd9 { cdesc = newdx.cdesc.ToLower(), code = newdx.code};
       db.Insert(newicd9);
  }
```

Performing the Insert(newicd9) with PetaPoco/Npgsql results in **no** value being given to the "timestamp" of the new record. How do I fix this such that the *PostgreSQL DEFAULT value is used?*

(I can assign the timestamp a value when creating the newicd9 instance, but I would like PostgreSQL to assign it with the DEFAULT now() method).

Any help is most appreciated.

Edit: The icd9 class is defined by the PetaPoco T4 template as:

```
    [TableName("nova.icd9")]
    [PrimaryKey("recid")]
    [ExplicitColumns]
    public partial class icd9 : chaosDB.Record<icd9>  
    {
        [Column] public int recid { get; set; }
        [Column] public string code { get; set; }
        [Column] public string cdesc { get; set; }
        [Column] public DateTime? timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How are you defining the icd9 class?

Comment: @harmic The icd9 class is defined by the PetaPoco T4 template. Please see added information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform an SQL `INSERT` into a table, if you provide a value for a column, then that value will be stored even if there was a default value for the column.

The only way to have the default applied is for the column not to be included in the SQL `INSERT` statement.

Inspecting the PetaPoco source code, I can see that it constructs `INSERT` statement using all columns except:

- Columns marked as 'result columns'
- the Primary key column

You could mark this time column as a result column (by decorating with `[ResultColumn]`) but by my reading of the code, that would also exclude it from the automatically generated `SELECT` clauses.

Disclaimer: While I do know a bit about postgresql, I don't know anything about .NET or petapoco!

Comment: Thanks. By using a Trigger with Before Insert, I can force a timestamp on null. Thanks again.